# Which java package or module does the control flow statements(for, while, do while) belong to?

Tags: java, module, package

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html
Just an example:
As we see here, we have multiple initializations and conditions. Where are these limitations defined in documentation?
I wanted to explore the limitations of those control flow statements like how many and what kind of arguments it can take, its limitation of scope, etc.? If you can provide a link to it, that would be great.

```
for(i=5,j=6,k=7; j<100, k >5, l<1000; i++, j--, k++){
    //do lot of things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've linked to the API. That's not where you find this stuff, as those parts are part of java, the language itself, and not any library.

Java consists of many things:

- A language specification
- A core library which you may assume is available on any VM without having to include it, it's just there.
- A VM (that runs class files)

You're looking for the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html), where you can find a description of this construct, called the **basic for**, in [Chapter §14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. :)